# How to combine entries of two arrays?

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

I'm feeling dumb, but I'm stuck, so I think I need to ask anyway. I'm looking for an algorithm that takes in input 2 arrays and gives in output all the possible 2 up to n pairwise combination, where n is the size of both the arrays; I'll explain: given the following arrays:

```
ArrayList<Elements> upper;
ArrayList<Elements> lower;
```

where, the content of these arrays is:

```
upper = [a, b, c]
lower = [A, B, C]
```

The algorithm has to output the following result:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Elements>> result;
```

where his content is the folowing one:

```
result = [
     [A, B, C],
     [A, B, c],
     [A, b, C],
     [A, b, c],
     [a, B, C],
     [a, B, c],
     [a, b, C],
     [a, b, c]
]
```

I've tried many many times, but without positive results.

I apologize for the triviality of the question and I hope in your help,

Regards

Comment: So show us what you have tried then, how should we know?

Comment: To me it looks like that's exactly what you're looking for, what's the difference? This is just a special case where there are only two lists.

Comment: @ToddSewell my apologies, you're right.